# Optimization of CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: objective-c, ios, avassetwriter

I am working on a project in which I generate a video from UIImage, with code I found around here, and I am struggling for some days now in order to optimize it (for about 300 images, it takes like 5 minutes on the simulator, and simply crashes on device because of the memory).

I'll begin with the working code I have today (I work with arc):

```
-(void) writeImageAsMovie:(NSArray *)array toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size duration:(int)duration 
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                   assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                   outputSettings:videoSettings];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];


    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:[[self.frames objectAtIndex:0] CGImage]];

    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer);

    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

    dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue =  dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
    int frameNumber = [self.frames count];

    [writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue usingBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Entering block with frames: %i", [self.frames count]);
        if(!self.frames || [self.frames count] == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        int i = 1;
        while (1)
        {
            if (i == frameNumber) 
            {
                break;
            }
            if ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) 
            {
                freeMemory();
                NSLog(@"inside for loop %d (%i)",i, [self.frames count]);
                UIImage *image = [self.frames objectAtIndex:i];
                CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
                CVPixelBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:imageRef];
                CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, TIME_STEP);

                CMTime lastTime=CMTimeMake(i, TIME_STEP); 

                CMTime presentTime=CMTimeAdd(lastTime, frameTime);       

                if (sampleBuffer) 
                {
                    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:sampleBuffer withPresentationTime:presentTime];
                    i++;
                    CVPixelBufferRelease(sampleBuffer);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [writerInput markAsFinished];
        [videoWriter finishWriting];
        self.frames = nil;

        CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);

    }];
}
```

And now the function to get the pixel buffer, with which I'm struggling:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    int width = CGImageGetWidth(image)*2;
    int height = CGImageGetHeight(image)*2;

    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:width], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey, nil];
    CVPixelBufferPoolRef pixelBufferPool; 
    CVReturn theError = CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &pixelBufferPool);
    NSParameterAssert(theError == kCVReturnSuccess);
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, width,
                                             height, 8, width*4, rgbColorSpace, 
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 
                                       height), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

First strange thing: as you can see in this function, I have to multiply the width and height by 2, otherwise, the result video is all messed up, and I can't understand why (I can post screenshots if it helps; the pixels seem to come from my image, but the width is not correct, and there is a large black square on the half bottom of the video).

Another problem is that it takes a really big amount of memory; I think that the pixel buffer could not be well deallocated, but I don't see why.

Finally, it is very slow, but I have two ideas to improve it, which I fail to use.

- The first is to avoid using UIImage to create my pixel buffers, since I generate the UIImage myself with (uint8_t *) data. I tried to use 'CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes', but it wouldn't work. Here is how I tried it:

  ```
  OSType pixFmt = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pxbuffer);
  CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, pixFmt, self.composition.srcImage.resultImageData, width*2, NULL, NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &pxbuffer);
  ```

(The arguments are the same as for the above functions; my image data are encoded in 16 bits per pixel, and I couldn't find a good OSType argument to give to the function.)
If someone know how to use it (maybe it's not possible with 16 bits/pixel data?), it would help me to avoid a really useless conversion.

- The second thing is that I would like to avoid kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB for my video. I guess it would be quicker to use something with fewer bits/pixel, but when I try it (I have tried all the kCVPixelFormatType_16XXXXX formats, with a context created with 5 bits/component and kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst), either it crashes, either the resulting video contains nothing (with kCVPixelFormatType_16BE555).

I know I ask a lot in only one post, but I am kind of lost in this code, I have tried so many combinations and none of them worked...

Comment: That should take at most 10s. Sounds like you're leaking and also duplicating your images data. How are you loading your images? Maybe there's a more direct way to load them into a CVPixelBuffer.

Comment: I managed just yesterday to get to something that does not leak! I am not really sure about what was the problem however, since I've been searching in all directions at the same time... I used the code from here: http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673 which I modified a lot and ended with something that does not leak... 
It is still not perfect, because I create the images from (int *) data and convert them again to that later, but at least it does not crash anymore because of memory issues...

Comment: do you have the final version of this code? I am having the same problem. I appreciate if you can share it. Thanks.

Comment: Having same problem can you help?